# Title and description aren't indexed with collective.dexteritytextindexer

Tags: indexing, plone, dexterity

I have lots of Dexterity content types, some of them are just containers and are left with just the Title and Description (from plone.app.dexterity.behaviors.metadata.IBasic behavior).

I can find them by searching the text inside their title or description.

But for some complex content types I'm using [collective.dexteritytextindexer](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.dexteritytextindexer) to index some more fields and it works fine, I can find the text on the fields I marked to be indexed.

However the Title and Description are no longer available for searching. I tried something like:

```
class IMyContent(form.Schema):
    """My content type description
    """

    dexteritytextindexer.searchable('title')
    dexteritytextindexer.searchable('description')

    dexteritytextindexer.searchable('long_desc')
    form.widget(long_desc = WysiwygFieldWidget)
    long_desc = schema.Text (
            title = _(u"Rich description"),
            description = _(u"Complete description"),
            required = False,
        )
    ...
```

But I can't see the content of title and description on the SearchableText column in the portal_catalog, and thus the results don't show them.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a reference this is the code I ended up writing:

```
@indexer(IMyDexterityType)
def searchableIndexer(context):
    transforms = getToolByName(context, 'portal_transforms')
    long_desc = context.long_desc // long_desc is a rich text field
    if long_desc is not None:
        long_desc = transforms.convert('html_to_text', long_desc).getData()
    contacts = context.contacts // contacts is also a rich text field
    if contacts is not None:
        contacts = transforms.convert('html_to_text', contacts).getData()

    return "%s %s %s %s" % (context.title, context.description, long_desc, contacts,)
grok.global_adapter(searchableIndexer, name="SearchableText")
```

Answer (score 5):

Got pretty much the same issue. Following the documentation on http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.dexteritytextindexer I used

```
from collective import dexteritytextindexer
from plone.autoform.interfaces import IFormFieldProvider
from plone.directives import form
from zope import schema
from zope.interface import alsoProvides

class IMyBehavior(form.Schema):

    dexteritytextindexer.searchable('specialfield')
    specialfield = schema.TextField(title=u'Special field')

alsoProvides(IMyBehavior, IFormFieldProvider)
```

to get my own fields indexed. However, the code

```
from plone.app.dexterity.interfaces import IBasic
from collective.dexteritytextindexer.utils import searchable

searchable(IBasic, 'title')
searchable(IBasic, 'description')
```

Didn't work. The import of IBasic fails. Seems this can easily be solved by importing

```
from plone.app.dexterity.behaviors.metadata import IBasic
```

Comment: I see you havemade a pull request to fix this error in the documentation and it got merged.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is probably that the field is coming from the IBasic or IDublineCore behaviour and not from your schema. I don't know enough about collective.dexteritytextindexer to know how to work around this, though.

Another option may be to just use plone.indexer and create your own SearchableText indexer that returns "%s %s %s" % (context.title, context.description, context.long_desc,). See the Dexterity docs for details.

Comment: Yes, it comes from IBasic behavior. And sure, I will take a look at plone.indexer. Thanks!