# Add contents of Dexterity NamedBlobFile to SearchableText

Tags: full-text-search, plone, dexterity

I've created a dexterity content type that has a NamedBlobFile as one of the fields (users will upload a .pdf). I'd like to have full-text indexing on that pdf -- like the ATFile type -- but not sure what I have to do to make that happen.

I've installed collective.dexteritytextindexer and have gotten some of the other fields added to searchable text by doing this:

```
searchable('paper_author')
paper_author = schema.Text(title=_(u"Author"), required=False)
```

I'm not sure what to do for the file field. Suggestions?

Comment: I asked something similar on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470152/title-and-description-arent-indexed-with-collective-dexteritytextindexer see my solution there.

Answer (score 0):

I think using the `searchable()` directive should work for NameBlobFiles too.

There is a converter in `collective.dexteritytextindexer` taking care of transforming the file contents into text so that it is indexable (see [the code at github](https://github.com/collective/collective.dexteritytextindexer/blob/master/collective/dexteritytextindexer/converters.py#L50)), which also applies for blobs (since the `INamedBlobFileField` subclasses `INamedFileField` for which the adapter is registered).

If it does not work its a bug, so please create an issue at the [collective.dexteritytextindexer issue tracker](https://github.com/collective/collective.dexteritytextindexer/issues).

If the problem is that the field is not defined in your code and you cannot use the `searchable` directive, there is also a `searchable` function (import from `.utils`!) which can be used outside the scope of the schema like this:

```
from plone.app.dexterity.behaviors.metadata import IBasic
from collective.dexteritytextindexer.utils import searchable

searchable(IBasic, 'title')
searchable(IBasic, 'description')
```